# ArgoCD : resource already exists and is not managed by SealedSecret

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, kubernetes-secrets, argocd, sealedsecret

I create `sealedsecret`  from `dockercondigjson` secret.
Created secret displayed in kubectl sealed secrets. But, I have message in ArgoCD, in events of sealedsecret:

> failed update: Resource "mysecret" already exists and not managed by SealedSecret

`K8s-manifests`(such as sealedsecret.yaml) pulled by ArgoCD from gitlab repository.
What is my mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Correct, sealed-secrets controller will not decrypt a sealedsecret into *an already existing* secret as a precaution. If you want that, annotate the existing secret with:

```
sealedsecrets.bitnami.com/managed: "true"
```

before creating the sealedsecret.

See docs: https://github.com/bitnami-labs/sealed-secrets/#managing-existing-secrets

Comment: Thanks! Repeat it in another application. My answer  below is just a lucky chance for specific configuration

Answer (score 0):

I solved issue by remove `dockerconfigjson` secret. After, that secret automatically recreated and error message is gone.